# Update multiple columns with multiple values in MSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with more than 70 columns, so how can I do something like this:

```
mysql_query("update `table` set (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`, `column5`, ...`column100`) = ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', ...'val100') where `anycolumn`='anyvalue'");
```

So I will implode the $_POST array instead of writing them one by one:

mysql_query("update `table` set (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`, `column5`, ...`column100`) = (".implode(', ',$_POST).") where `anycolumn`='anyvalue'");

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Do NOT simply implode the `$_POST` array and add it to your query. Aside from the obvious possibility that you'll include data in the wrong place, you are leaving yourself wide open to an SQL Injection attack.

Comment: @raina77ow, it doesn't work !:
" update `clients` set (`name`, `id_num`) = ('123','2317769756') where id='1' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the alternate format for the UPDATE command

```
UPDATE table SET
       column1 = 'value1',
       column2 = 'value2',
         :
       column100 = 'value100';
```

Using this format, you can construct the SQL code in PHP. For **example** :-

```
$updated_fields = array();
$sql  = 'UPDATE table SET ';
foreach ($_POST as $column => $field) {
    if (isset($field) && strlen($field)) {
        $updated_fields[] = "`".$column."` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($field)."'";
    }
}
$sql  = implode(", ", $updated_fields)."WHERE somecondition = 'somevalue' ";
```

Some notes

- This code assumes all your $_POST variables will have a corresponding
  database column.
- You will have to fill in the condition after the WHERE clause.
- Take note of the comments regarding SQL injections
- Use something like PDO, rather than the mysql_*** commands

Comment: Thanks bro it works, but needs little corrections:
1- $updated_fields instead of $update.
2- isset($field) && strlen($field) instead of isset($_POST[$field]) && strlen($_POST[$field]).
3- mysql_real_escape_string($field) instead of mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field]).

Comment: Well spotted @Samer. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected your syntax error in php , but the query is not valid.

```
$query = "update table set (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, ...column100) = ('".implode("','",$_POST)."') where anycolumn='anyvalue'";
echo $query;
```

Try this solution using associative array :

```
<?php

$_POST= array(0,1,2,3);
$params=array(
'column1'=>$_POST['0'],'column2'=>$_POST['1'],'column3'=>$_POST['3']
);

foreach($params as $key=>$value){
    $partQuery[]="$key = $value" ;
}
$query = "update table set( ".implode(' , ',$partQuery)." ) where anycolumn='anyvalue'";
echo $query;
?>
```

But pay attention to **sql injection** , and try using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_` which is deprecated and will not be supported any more in future versions of php.

Comment: It's 2013. It's PHP 5.5. Why still using **mysql_** ?

Comment: why telling this to me , i know it's deprecated , i'm just correcting his mistakes :) , tell that to op

Comment: That's why there's no downvote :p But more likely to see a warning if an answer contains that ancient crap :p

Comment: still not work: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`name`,`id_num`) = ('test','123456') where `id`='1'' at line 1.
This's the query:
    "update `clients` set (`name`,`id_num`) = ('123','2317769756') where `id`='1'"

Comment: @Samer check my new answer  , it may help you